# Referencing overloaded top-level Kotlin functions reflectively

Tags: function, kotlin, reflection, overloading

In brief, how can one reference / iterate reflectively over overloaded top-level functions in Kotlin, such as `kotlin.io.println`?

---

Given the following:

```kotlin
object Bar {
    fun foo(x: Int) = Unit
    fun foo(x: Byte) = Unit
    fun foo(x: Float) = Unit
}
```

I can iterate over the various overloads of `foo` by doing:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    Bar::class.memberFunctions
        .filter { kFunction -> kFunction.name == "foo" }
        .forEach { kFunction -> println(kFunction) }
}
```

Which produces:

```
fun com.example.Bar.foo(kotlin.Byte): kotlin.Unit
fun com.example.Bar.foo(kotlin.Float): kotlin.Unit
fun com.example.Bar.foo(kotlin.Int): kotlin.Unit
```

*However*, if the various overloads of `foo` are defined top-level (*outside of a class or object definition*) such as simply:

```kotlin
fun foo(x: Int) = Unit
fun foo(x: Byte) = Unit
fun foo(x: Float) = Unit
```

Then there doesn't seem to be a way to reference them.

I tried being tricky using a top-level function in my example (*such as `main`*) to access the synthetic class:

```kotlin
::main::class.memberFunctions
    .filter { kFunction -> kFunction.name == "foo" }
    .forEach { kFunction -> println(kFunction) }
```

But it pukes on the fact that it's synthetic:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This class is an internal synthetic class generated by the Kotlin compiler, such as an anonymous class for a lambda, a SAM wrapper, a callable reference, etc. It's not a Kotlin class or interface, so the reflection library has no idea what declarations does it have. Please use Java reflection to inspect this class.
```

How can I reference top-level overloaded functions in Kotlin?

More specifically, top-level overloaded functions defined in other packages / modules such as `kotlin.io.println`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top level functions by definition don't have a declaring class.

```
::println.javaClass.declaringClass //will return null
```

so you don't have a class to use reflection on, and consequently, you can't enumerate the top level members of a package.([Some magic can be done though, if you are willing to trade your soul](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520328/7117454))

The only way you can reference ambiguous top level functions is by helping the compiler to resolve the ambiguity like this:

```
val functionReference: (Int)->Unit = ::foo
```

and then you can call functionReference()

Comment: I don't mind trading my soul for the right price ;-) Thanks for your answer, I'll be playing with that magic in the meantime.